# In unit test of TestNG. How should I configure to make @SpringBootTest run only once

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testng

I have many unit test files, how can I avoid running multiple unit test classes that spring will start multiple times(Start spring once, run multiple test files)

I am using testng to unit test a SpringBoot project.I created a BaseTest to set the necessary configuration.Every test class extends this BaseTest.

BaseTest::

```
package comTest;

import ...;

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Rollback(value = false)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)
public class BaseTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
}
```

UT class::

```
package comTest.testDemo;

import ...;

public class TotalTest extends BaseTest {
     @Test
     ....
}
====================================================
package comTest.testDemo;

import ...;

public class ControllerTest extends BaseTest {
     @Test
     ....
}
```

testng.xml::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite">
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="demo">
        <classes>
            <class name="comTest.testDemo.ControllerTest">
            </class>
            <class name="comTest.testDemo.TotalTest">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

when I run this `testng.xml`,The console returns the following results::

[image]
[image]

I have two test classes that inherit BaseTeat so that spring starts twice, which greatly slows down the test run time. Is necessary to extends BaseTest in my unit tests.

***How should I achieve that all test classes can be run only by loading spring once.***

Comment: If your tests use the same config and run in the same JVM (not sure how TestNG does that). The context (and thus application) should be reused as the Test Context framework of spring will cache and reuse it. However if something in the configuration is different (test execution listeners, properties, ...) it will crate a new context.

Comment: Yes, all test classes are running in the same JVM. How do I reuse a context configuration?@M. Deinum

Comment: Reusing is automatic, unless there is a difference in config or an `@DirtiesContext` on the test class. If it isn't it might be related to how TestNG is launching things (or how your `testng.xml` is written) but my TestNG knowledge is not that extensive.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With reference to your suggestion, I grouped my test cases, and the test classes of the same startup environment were executed in the same group to solve the problem smoothly.thank you for your help

Comment: You might want to turn your solution into a self-answer so that it is helpful for others.